# Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError for Play + Scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework, aws-sdk

- Mac OSX 10.11.6
- Scala version 2.11.8
- aws-java-sdk 1.11.57
- Play Framework 2.5.10

I am new to Scala and Play Framework.

I have a following class that is to be injected into a controller.

```
class BoardRepositoryImpl extends BoardRepository {

  private val tableName = "tyo_boards"

  private val table = DynamoDBProvider.db.getTable(tableName)

  override def findAll: List[Board] = {

    val hashCondition = new Condition()
      .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
      .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue("841120161129"))

    table.scan(new ScanSpec())
      .asScala
      .toList
      .map( i => new Board(
        i.getString(BoardRepository.codeDate),
        i.getList(BoardRepository.withLimit)
          .asScala
          .toList,
        i.getString(BoardRepository.time)
      )
    )
  }

}

object BoardRepository {
  val codeDate = "code_date"
  val withLimit = "with_limit"
  val time = "time"
}
```

**The controller is**

```
@Singleton
class BoardsController @Inject()(repository: BoardRepositoryImpl) extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    val boards = repository.findAll

    Ok(views.html.boards(boards))
  }

}
```

**The result is**

```
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at infrastructure.BoardRepositoryImpl.<init>(BoardRepositoryImpl.scala:18)
  while locating infrastructure.BoardRepositoryImpl
    for parameter 0 at controllers.BoardsController.<init>(BoardsController.scala:13)
  at controllers.BoardsController.class(BoardsController.scala:13)
  while locating controllers.BoardsController
    for parameter 2 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:43)
  while locating router.Routes
  while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
  while locating play.api.routing.Router
    for parameter 0 at play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler.<init>(HttpRequestHandler.scala:200)
  while locating play.api.http.JavaCompatibleHttpRequestHandler
  while locating play.api.http.HttpRequestHandler
    for parameter 4 at play.api.DefaultApplication.<init>(Application.scala:221)
  at play.api.DefaultApplication.class(Application.scala:221)
  while locating play.api.DefaultApplication
  while locating play.api.Application

1 error
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
     com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:405)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceInjector.instanceOf(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:400)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
     play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:168)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
     play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:164)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
     scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:131)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
     scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:129)
     play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$1$$anonfun$get$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:121)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
     scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
     java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Honestly, I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: My wild guess would be to try to avoid initializing the value `table` in the constructor. Try declaring it as a lazy val or do it inside the method `findAll`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Comment: But I need to understand why.

Comment: The reason was probably that at the time you accessed `DynamoDBProvider` it was not reay yet (maybe it depended on some other thing that first needs to bootstrap) and therefore threw an exception when guice tried to instantiate your repository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I am yet to understand it. Maybe I need to check the timing of instantiations somehow.